# Servo Speed Control

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, servo

How can i make my servo do this but slower?

```
if(angle == 140)
```

angle = 159;

else

if(angle == 159)

angle = 140;

This is the whole code:

```
    #include <Servo.h>

const int TOUCH_SENSOR_PIN   = 6;   // Arduino pin connected to touch sensor's pin
const int TOUCH_SENSOR_PIN2   = 7 ;
const int SERVO_PIN          = 9;   // Arduino pin connected to servo motor's pin

Servo servo; // create servo object to control a servo

// variables will change:
int angle = 140;           // the current angle of servo motor
int lastTouchState;      // the previous state of touch sensor
int currentTouchState;   // the current state of touch sensor
int lastTouchState2;      // the previous state of touch sensor 2
int currentTouchState2;   // the current state of touch sensor 2


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);      // initialize serial
  pinMode(TOUCH_SENSOR_PIN, INPUT);
  pinMode(TOUCH_SENSOR_PIN2, INPUT);
  servo.attach(SERVO_PIN);       // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object

  servo.write(angle);
  currentTouchState = digitalRead(TOUCH_SENSOR_PIN);
  currentTouchState2 = digitalRead(TOUCH_SENSOR_PIN2);
}

void loop() {
  lastTouchState    = currentTouchState;  // save the last state
  currentTouchState = digitalRead(TOUCH_SENSOR_PIN);  //read new state 
  
  lastTouchState2    = currentTouchState2;  // save the last state
  currentTouchState2 = digitalRead(TOUCH_SENSOR_PIN2);  //read new state 

  if((lastTouchState == LOW && currentTouchState == HIGH) || (lastTouchState2 == LOW && currentTouchState2 == HIGH)) {

    if(angle == 140)
      angle = 159;
    else
    if(angle == 159)
      angle = 140;


    // control servo motor arccoding to the angle
    servo.write(angle);
    

  }  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can control the speed of the servo by making it rotating several little steps instead of giving it the final demand angle, something like this.

```
  if(angle <= 140){
    for (; angle<= 150; angle += 1) {
      myservo.write(angle);
      delay(15);
    }
  }
  else if(angle >= 150){
    for (; angle >= 140; angle -= 1) {
      myservo.write(angle);
      delay(15);
    }
  }
```

you can adjust the speed by changing the delay value in both for-loops.
A full working example can be found in the examples provided by the Arduino IDE under Servo -> Sweep I guess.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XrwIKyxxxSQ

See https://github.com/netlabtoolkit/VarSpeedServo

VarSpeedServo.h

From the Readme

> NOTE: This library is no longer maintained due to hardware dependencies and wide variety of devices to support. As an alternative, I have created VarSpeedPython, which is a module that can be used on any python platform (e.g. CircuitPython or MicroPython) or any implementation of Python. VarSpeedPython is does not have any hardware dependencies, and is designed to be called from within an event loop (and therefore does not block).

> VarSpeedPython provides the ability to move from one position to another over a period of time, and with a specified number of steps, and with an easing function for the move. It can be applied to Servos, LEDs, any other actuator or output that needs to change from one value to another over time.